# Error while importing matplotlib in Anaconda

Tags: python, matplotlib, anaconda, digital-ocean

I frequently use Digitaloceans service to run longer Python scripts on the cloud. I use the standard settings for my droplet (Ubuntu 16.04.2 x64, 2GB memory, 40 GB disk space). 
Once the remote machine is running, I install [Anaconda](https://repo.continuum.io/archive/Anaconda3-4.4.0-Linux-x86_64.sh). This works nicely, and I follow precisely the same steps every time.

Now I never had problems importing matplotlib before. This time, importing matplotlib throws an error:
`ImportError: libGL.so.1: cannot open shared object file`
Uninstalling and reinstalling it using `conda` did not change anything.

Does anyone experience a similar problem, or knows a solution to this?

Comment: Have you tried [this](https://github.com/ContinuumIO/docker-images/issues/49)

Comment: @FredrikPihl I've now directly installed Python3, and the desired packages with pip, which works fine. Thanks for the link, anyway!

Comment: Glad you solved it!